# How to play a video file from SD card

Tags: android, media-player, android-videoview

I want to play a video file on android emulator that I have stored in sd card.
This is my code..

```
public class AndroidVideoViewActivity extends Activity {

    private VideoView videoView=null;
    private String PATH="mnt/sdcard/bmxskills.3gp";
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer=null;
    private MediaController mediaController=null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        VideoView videoView=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        videoView.setVideoPath("mnt/sdcard/bmxskills.3gp");

        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start();

    }
}
```

But when I run on emulator it shows blank screen.Please help.I have added the permissions required that is internet and external storage.

Comment: @Sunjay have you check my Answer?

Comment: @Nik I checked your answer but still I am getting same result.Do I have to create a video player or does android have a built in video player to play videos?

Comment: @Sunjay Please check this in Device.

Comment: which emulator are you using? the arm emulators are very slow, if you use the x86 emulator you shouldn't have as many problems

Comment: I have created raw folder and I have put video and its working.Now I want to add many videos how to do?Thanks...

Answer (score 5):

Please check [this link](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/11/play-3gp-video-file-using-mediaplayer.html)

**OR**

Replace `videoView.setVideoPath("mnt/sdcard/bmxskills.3gp");`

with `videoView.setVideoPath("/sdcard/bmxskills.3gp");`

Answer (score 3):

Use below code for that.

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/myvideoview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String SrcPath = "/sdcard/Video/Android in Spaaaaaace!_low.mp4";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        VideoView myVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);
        myVideoView.setVideoPath(SrcPath);
        myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        myVideoView.requestFocus();
        myVideoView.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not test running video on the emulator itself, if you have a device laying around, use that instead. The Android emulator is quite terrible when it coming to handling videos correctly, so you may get a lot of problems that wouldn't normally be there on any Android device.